# Hotmail account is not receiving email from web server

Tags: shared-hosting, mail, hotmail

I have a client with an ecommerce site. It's working fine but we realised that Hotmail accounts are not receiving emails from the site (eg: the receipt when someone orders a product).

We tested by creating an account and sending mail via Roundcube to a Hotmail account but got no results. Server mail logs say the email's been sent. We do not get any error messages bouncing back. The server does not appear to be on any blacklists and, of course, we've checked the spam folders.

Would anyone know what's going on here?

Server is a shared-server with LAMP stack.

Update: the server is able to receive emails from Hotmail. Replying to this email works.

Comment: Maybe ask your provider to give you a new IP (in a different range?)

Comment: Check out my comment below my answer, you can contact delist@messaging.microsoft.com  and check if the IP address is listed, but I repeat, this is more a server admin job.  If the IP is blocked it is affecting many people.

Answer (score 2):

I've been through this, you will likely find that the server's IP address has been blacklisted by Microsoft.  Does your domain have valid SPF and DKIM records in DNS?  If not, that will be what has caused it possibly.

You don't say whether or not there is a bounce message, this will tell you the problem, as usual.  Because it is a shared server, all you need is someone else on the server to spam Hotmail/Live/Outlook and the entire server is blacklisted.  I would be reporting it to the server admins.

Comment: But wouldnt that result in a bounce back message?

Comment: Yes, it should.  Check the mail logs if you have access.  I would suggest getting sysadmins to investigate this further, they can dig deeper than you'll be able to without root access.

Comment: Considering replying to emails works, the problem shouldn't be the IP being blacklisted. I think you should call Microsoft!

Comment: Many anti-spam filters will not send e-mails back. This is called backspatter and causes more problems than it solves. Keep in mind that some ISPs and other services, especially free e-mail providers, use their own blacklists.  While I do understand why they do this, I do not agree with it if they are not feeding the blacklists with spam reports. It is like bringing a food to class and not having enough to share. Think Jeff Spicoli when he brought the pizza to class and Mr. Hand dressed him down. I digress.

Comment: @closetnoc pizza not withstanding, Microsoft hotmail/live/outlook does send a bounce advising that it is a blacklist issue.

    550 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [2xx.2xx.1x.8x] blocked using FBLW15; To request removal from this list please forward this message to delist@messaging.microsoft.com

Comment: @Steve Agreed. None of them should be sending replies. My point is that if they are detecting spam, it is likely very possible for them to feed the blacklists as a service back to the community and to help honest people diagnose what may have gone wrong. Don't bogart that ping my friend, pass it over to me.... (everyone sing along!)

Comment: @Steve Sometimes you just have to laugh... look at what I found?? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87596/where-does-dont-bogart-that-joint-come-from

Comment: @closetnoc yes, adding to public blacklists is good.  But don't forget that the average punter has no idea why emails are not getting through, they likely don't even know about blacklists.  So the bounce message that the IP address is blocked is a good heads up.  http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2011/07/dont-bogart-that-joint-my-friend.html

Comment: @Steve Yeah. Some do it. Some don't. Replies have been helpful to me in the past and that has been very appreciated. It is just that a bunch of backspatter will trip others to report you to a blacklist (right or wrong). I personally feel that no-one should be pinged for doing the right thing when someone else is doing the wrong thing. But that is just silly silly me. ;-)